# JSON to Map[String,JsObject] with Play 2.0?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new to both Play! & Scala, but I'm trying to make a service that will map the JSON request to a Map[String,JsObject] (or Map[String,JsValue], I'm not sure about the distinction), and then output a list of the keys recursively through the map (preferably as a tree).

But I'm having start issues:

```
def genericJSONResponse = Action(parse.json) {
  request => request.body
  var keys = request.keys
  Ok("OK")
}
```

What I would expect here was for keys to be filled with the keys from the request, but of course, it doesn't compile. How should I approach this, given the description above?

Thanks in advance for helping out a Scala noob :-)

Nik

Comment: Have you read through this wiki? https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaJsonRequests

You'll have to map the keys manually or using an implicit object to map them to an object.

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaJsonGenerics

Comment: Also something to bear in mind is using mutable values/collections in scala is not advised - as can be seen [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-idiom-immutable-code-functional-programming-immutability)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`JsValue` is the base class for all JSON values. `JsObject` is a subtype of `JsValue` (along with `JsNull`, `JsUndefined`, `JsBoolean`, `JsNumber`, `JsString`, and `JsArray`). Take a look at JSON spec if it's unclear: http://json.org/

If you know that the JSON in the body request is a JSON object (as opposed to other types listed above) you can pattern-match it:

```
def genericJSONResponse = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body match {
    case JsObject(fields) => Ok("received object:" + fields.toMap + '\n')
    case _ => Ok("received something else: " + request.body + '\n')
  }
}
```

`fields.toMap` is of type you wanted: `Map[(String, JsValue)]` so you can use `map` or `collect` to process the object's keys recursively. (By the way, you can use `fields` directly, since it's a `Seq[(String, JsValue)]` and supports `map` and `collect` as well).

Comment: @niklassaers I'm glad you like it.